# Is a solo cello strong enough to make a piano ring?

Tags: piano, acoustics, cello

I attended a concert once where a trombone soloist played his instrument pointing towards the strings of a grand piano (lid propped fully open, pianist depressing the pedal).  The effect was amazing; the trombone made not only its fundamental frequency ring but also many overtones.  The result was a powerful "echo" effect, shimmering and brilliant.

I'm wondering if anyone has tried a similar setup with cello.  Would a cello solo playing a loud melody on its A string be a strong enough sound to cause a grand piano (lid open, sustain pedal depressed) to ring sympathetically?  Does anyone know of a piece in the literature that does this?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Sympathetic vibration produced by a grand with open lid, sustain pedal held down,  will happen from any source loud enough.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want this effect and don't have access to a grand piano, there are effects plugins for digital recording use that emulate it.  Some use modeling, and some use a convolution reverb based on the impulse response of a real piano.

Comment: A fun experience but I doubt it's significant enough for a recital or concert.

Comment: @Theodore  there's a  stomp-box for nearly any effect under the sun :-) .   Hard to find a trombone with a built-in transceiver tho'

Answer (score 5):

Generally yes. But you need to keep in mind that brass instruments tend to have quite some dynamic range. While it is possible to play the cello quite strongly you cannot get the same amount of loudness from it. Also it is quite easy to direct the sound of a brass instrument into the piano (well, not with all of them. Tuba for example does not lend itself to that very well). With a cello this is much harder.

So most likely if you were to do this you would get a much less audible effect.

Out of curiosity: Why was the trombone soloist playing a horn?

Edit: But it would be very well possible to install a little piezo pickup on the cello and install some small speakes inside the piano that transfer the sound of the cello to the piano.

Comment: to be clear, he was playing a trombone

Comment: So, yes, it will "work," but without being as directional as a brass instrument and without its dynamic range, probably not loud enough to be significant in performance.  Is that the gist of it?

Comment: "Why was the trombone soloist playing a horn?"  I suspect OP is using "horn" to mean "brass instrument" or possibly "bell", not "the-instrument-also-known-as-French-horn".

Comment: Yes, I used the word "horn" as slang for "brass instrument -

Comment: @nuggethead Yes, more or less. Of course, what’s significant in performance depends on the size of the room/hall, so in a chamber concert this might work. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I’m not speaking english natively, so I didn’t make that connection to slang (I thought this was what Jazz people call a saxophone).

Comment: (Now I'm picturing Tower of Power's legendary "horn section" as composed entirely of French Horns...)

Comment: Also probably works best with low-pitch instruments?  You're not likely to reproduce this effect with a flute or oboe, possibly even with a trumpet, which is louder but still too high a range.  The tuba would probably be great if you could somehow rotate the tuba (and maybe the player) so it's pointing the right direction.  Might be easier with a walkaround sousaphone?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Not exactly. Of course, if your instrument is too high you will only get high resonance. But what’s more important is having a strong harmonic spectrum, to stimulate as many strings as possible. But else you can do this in a large range of pitch. You can try this by singing into the piano.

Comment: @AndyBonner Or maybe alpine horns?